# Find minimum of function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, fourier-analysis

I am given the fuction

$$(a, b) \mapsto \int_{-1}^{1} |x^{2} -a -bx|^{2} dx.$$

And have to find the point $(a, b) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$ at which the above fuction attains its minimum and find this minimum.

No idea where to begin, so any help is appreciated. This question is asked in a book on Fourier Analysis so perhaps it relies on such techniques.

Comment: So, is the function  $f: \mathbb{R}^{2} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(a,b):=\int_{-1}^{1}\left|x^{2}-a-bx \right|^{2}dx$? If that is true, can you try to solve the integral and then to find the miminum of $f$?

Comment: Note that the absolute value bars are a red herring as the expression is squared, so you can remove them.  Now you have the integral of a polynomial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(a,b)=\int_{-1}^1 \left(-a-b x+x^2\right)^2 \, dx=2 a^2-\frac{4 a}{3}+\frac{2 b^2}{3}+\frac{2}{5}$$
$$\frac{\partial f }{\partial a}=4 a-\frac{4}{3};\;\frac{\partial f }{\partial b}=(4 b)/3$$
Derivatives are both zero at $\left(\frac{1}{3},0\right)$

It is a *minimum* because Hessian matrix of second derivatives is constant and positive.